# Dell U2312HM not powering on

Tags: display, dvi, cable, displayport

I have such a monitor, and since some months I have a VERY strange problem, at least for me. I generally use to completely turn off the current with an electric switch (I'm Italian, hope this term means what I have in my mind) since the monitor and PC are in my room, and I have a PS4 and my PC connected, one with DVI and the other one with DP. When I turn the current ON with the switch in the morning sometimes the monitor seems dead, completely.

I can remove any video cable connected, the power cable, changing it, nothing, it's completely dead. If I wait 1 hour, or 2, then if I'm lucky, pressing the power button the monitor turns on and works, and if I turn off but I don't switch electricity off with the switch, the monitor still works, with both PS4 and PC.

As soon as I turn electricity OFF again, then the problem MAY appear again or not: this seems completely random, except made for the fact that in the last weeks I noticed that if there are both the DVI and DP cable connected, then 90% of the times the monitor doesn't power on, instead if I have only the DP cable there are good chances it works.

What could it be? I'am really confused.

Comment: Can you please in the future format your question so it can actually be read? You wouldn't write a single paragraph in any setting, so why do we get, the single block of text?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the socket board you are using (socket board = one powercord to a row of multiple power outputs) has no protection for overvoltage, you can have spikes in voltage as you switch your devices on. These spikes are often also impacting devices such as displays (HDMI is very vulnerable and I bricked my graphics card once by first starting the monitor which caused a surge to run directly in the not overvoltage protected inputs of my graphics card).

The overvoltage will harm the ICs inside the devices, but there could be an OV-protection. The fact that it will work after you wait several hours could indicate that the (protection) circuit is able to recover.

So, you could try to keep the monitor shutdown until you powered on your other devices and then power it on.
As we don't know further details apart from that we're talking about a monitor, this is only an assumption of mine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply first. I meant a power strip (found that name finally lol) anyway. So basically from what you said it may be that some power spikes damaged the ICs in the monitor but the protection circuit is able to recover it after some hours? Anyway, giving some more info, I always had 2 power strips (also now) which are chained one another.I have an external HDD powered, my PC, my PS4, a USB hub and nothing else. So you're suggesting trying to power on first my PC (the other devices are already powered on as soon as I switch the power strip on) and then try if the monitor works?

Comment: Officially chaining power strips is a bad thing due to two main reasons: 1) you can exceed the max. output power (here in Germany 3500W) if you think you've got so much outlets (unlikely though) 2) there is often a protective earth conductor, so you've got 3 pairs of wires: two for the alternating current and one protective earth conductor. If you plug many power strips in row, the resistance of this protective ground wire can increase and FI security is harmed. However, this shouldn't be a real problem... You say the PS4 starts automatically?

Comment: Ok I understand. No, the PS4 doesn't start automatically, the other devices do. Yesterday I wasn't at home so I forgot some other devices. I also have a LED strip which is powered there and also my audio system for my PC, which is powered in these two strips. Obviously they don't power on automatically. So you're suggesting to powering ON all of them and only then, trying to powering on the monitor, did I understand correctly?